# How to access environment variable from command prompt?

Tags: windows

On Windows 7, I created a system environment variable.
Surprised to find that I cannot access its value.

```
JETTY_HOME=D:\workspace\jetty-distribution-9.4.8.v20171121

C:\Users\me>cd %JETTY_HOME%

C:\Users\me>set

....
JETTY_HOME=D:\workspace\jetty-distribution-9.4.8.v20171121
....

C:\Users\me>cd JETTY_HOME
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plain cd command does not change the current drive from c: to d:. The /d switch tells the command to also change the drive. So:

```
CD /D %JETTY_HOME%
```

Works from any drive.

Comment: why wouldn't `cd %JETTY_HOME%` work? Your solution requires me to know the value of the variable.

Comment: Actually you dont need to know it. The plain cd command does not change to a different drive. The /d switch allows you to do that - to any drive set in the variable.